# Check if pdf are the same

Tags: pdf

I have a folder with houdreds of pdf files with different names. Some of them have the same contents the is identical. I would like to find out which pdf files are the same and collect them in another folder. Is there an open source program or online program that can do this check? And hopefully also the movement in a separate folder. Or a VBA macro that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

To find duplicate pdf's in a folder you can use **Adobe Acrobat**, by Adobe Acrobat you can find duplicate pdf's as well as you can delete them